# Removing lines inside a polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, vertices

The situation is this:

[image: Text]
[image: Text]
[image: Text]
[image: Text]

I need to remove the lines inside the blue polygon, I have tried with dissolve and delete holes processing tools but they didn't work.
I would like to know if there is a solution. File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1itv2Gpr4fPN6TpeSKJDRCZEox0hnFP76/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Dissolve should work. Could there be a very small gap which is not visible? Try "Snap points to grid" then Dissolve.

Comment: If it is just for display purposes, set the border color to be the same as the inside color

Comment: You have the source data with the wrong geometry, so one way: 1) Select on the panel: Analysis tools->Vector geometry->Correct geometries; 2) Then select the polygon you are interested in ->Vector->Geo-processing->Connection by... select the checkbox - "Only selected objects" ->Click on the button "Run" and that's it...

Answer (score 3):

As BERA said, dissolve is the tool. The trick is in create a field with values equals for each contiguous feature to dissolve. So, I digitizing, approximately, your shapefile and it looks as follows:

[image]

If I want to dissolve all features, I have to create a field (e.g. common) with the same values in each record. Following image presents result of Dissolve (selecting field common) and, the attributes table corresponds to original layer (polygon_test). All features were dissolved as expected.

[image]

Now, I want to dissolve only contiguous features observed in following image. Field named commond2 must be selected in this case.

[image]

Result of running dissolve tool (deselecting all features selected previously) is as expected:

[image]

**Editing Note:**

With your shapefile, blue polygon above considered was selected in following image with QGIS. It is a Multipart feature.

[image]

So, run 'Multipart to singlepart' processing tool with default values. Result is visualized in below image. Additional created features have same id (82267) as original parent feature. So, id field is the one to be used in Dissolve tool.

[image]

Afterward Dissolve, in following image can be observed "fusion" of features as expected.

[image]

Comment: The fact is that in my case It doesn't work, because there aren't different polygons but it's only a unique polygon, infact if I try to select a part everything will be selected as you cans see in my second image, so If I use dissolve nothing changes; if you want I can send you the shapefile so you will see

Comment: Ok. Edit your question and put the Dropbox or Google Drive link in it.

Comment: ok, I have just put the link

Comment: Please, see complete process in my **Editing Note**.

Comment: when I run multipart to single part this window pops up and even if i fill the parameters nothing starts   https://i.gyazo.com/7934c8f141eb1f7a2555531398bb2443.png

Comment: What is your QGIS version and operating system?

Comment: windows 10, qgis latest update